# Cannot find module './src/data' with vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

I created a project with vue-cli 4.1.1, and after running yarn serve, i got the following error

```
Error: [BABEL] C:\dev\vuestudy\src\main.js: Cannot find module './src/data' (While processing: "C:\\dev\\vuestudy\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-plugin-babel\\preset.js")
```

Any tips on this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Kousha and Dave are right,after waiting for the core-js package update, I created a new project, and now it's working.

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading npm packages today

Comment: Same here with react / rush / pnpm project

Comment: Same here with react app

Comment: Same here, react / rush / pnpm

Comment: same here with react app :fire

Comment: Same here, with vue. This is what I get for trying out a hipster garbage fire

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like there's been a bad build of npm package `core-js-compat`. This is a deep-down dependency of Babel. Lots of things will be affected, things that use Babel.

You will experience this problem if you have core-js-compat v.3.4.6. You can check this by doing `npm list core-js-compat`. The problem is apparently fixed by v.3.4.7, which was pushed out pretty quickly, about half-an-hour later, but unfortunately it takes a while to spread out through the repositories. You can either wait until an `npm update` gets you v.3.4.7 or you can go manually download v.3.4.7 if you want to get going right away.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug with core-js-compat v3.4.6, but already the fix has gone with v3.4.7. See https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/712 for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to force install the not-broken version with

`npm i core-js-compat@3.4.7 --save`

It worked on my machine™

Answer (score 0):

With Vue / Nuxt, you can delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and do an `npm install` to fix this issue.