# Newly created React app crashes on live server

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal, babeljs

Whenever i create a react app using create-react-app and run `npm run start` it crashes.

This is the error i am getting in terminal.

```
Failed to compile ../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
Error: [BABEL]/Users/toures/Desktop/REACT/SecondSummit/try1/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js: 
Cannot find module './src/data' 
(While processing: "/Users/toures/Desktop/REACT/SecondSummit/try1/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/dependencies.js$0$9")
```

Can anyone guide me? Thanks.

Comment: its the same thing a lot of people experiences today,
more info on this thread. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144825/cannot-find-module-src-data-with-vue-cli
basically you just have to wait for npm cache to push a new version of core js compat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module './src/data' with vue-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144825/cannot-find-module-src-data-with-vue-cli)

Comment: Yes thankyou, the thread answered my query.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've fixed it by deleting the node_modules folder, then running npm install.