# Error: [BABEL] /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/index.js: Cannot find module './src/data'

Tags: babeljs, create-react-app

getting the following issue in build using npm run build.
in a create-react-app project.

also appearing in another nextjs project.

Anyone has any idea about this?
cannot stack trace anywhere, it seem to come from babel.

For the case with create-react-app, i cannot change any of the babel config in this.

Comment: Would be interested to know too. Had this error appear today and no changes in my package.json so maybe some downstream dependency. Here is the error:
`Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/core-js-compat/helpers.js
...
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js (While processing: "/usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js$0$29")
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
`

Comment: Seems like downgrading `core-js-compat` to `3.4.5` fixes the issue (as a temp workaround)

Comment: hmm, found this other thread, i guess mine is duplicate.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144825/error-running-yarn-serve-in-a-project-created-with-vue-cli-4-1-1


comments refers to https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/712

but looks like pending some npm cache to let the new version install properly.

sounds like it will auto resolve itself soon.
or downgrade as above mention if applicable for the project.

Comment: Also experienced this issue on a Gatsby project.

Comment: The issue has been resolved in core-js-compat version 3.4.7. You should be able to do: `npm install core-js-compat@3.4.7` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, confirmed v3.4.6 is stale. @Bots & Dave V - Thanks. Saved my day, my backside and a production deployment!